# Counting how many times an equation is true for items from an array

Tags: math, logic, equation

I have an array containing integers from 1 to 1000. I'm trying to count how many times this equation is true `A + B + C + D = E` where `A <= B <= C <= D` and A, B, C, D, E are all items from the array. Could you guys suggest any solutions?

The array contains **all** integers from 1 to 1000, so 1, 2, 3, 4, .. , 999, 1000. The numbers A - D **can be the same number** from the array.

Comment: Your problem statement is rather vague. Does your array contain **all** the integers from 1 to 1000, or just a subset? Can it contain duplicates? Can the numbers A–D correspond to the same number, or must they all be chosen from different items in the array? Also, what solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: My array contains all integers from 1 to 1000, so 1, 2, 3, 4 ... , 999, 1000. The numbers A - D can correspond to the same number, yes. I've tried one solution but it was incredibly slow and too complicated, contained many for loops within each other.

Comment: What is the specific programming problem you have with this? Can you provide a [mre] of the best you have managed? Preparing the data in suitable data structures and a simple case of checking the equation for the easier sets of four numbers should be achievable.

Comment: "I've tried one solution " Show an MRE of that please.

Comment: @Yunnosch sadly I've erased the code that I had, but if I come up with something in a bit I'll post it here

Comment: @tomboborbo When you do, please add it to your question together with a full description of the problem you're trying to solve. This additional information doesn't belong in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate number of integer partitions for every value E in range 1..1000 into 4 parts.

Python function `countparts` to calculate number of such partitions.

```
def cp(n, k, m):
    if k == 0:
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    res = 0
    for i in range(min(n + 1, m + 1)):
        res += cp(n - i, k - 1, i)
    return res

def countparts(n, k):
    return cp(n - k, k, n - k + 1)

print(countparts(8, 4))

>> 5    (1115, 1124, 1133, 1223, 2222)
```

But it works slowly for large arguments.

Also [at this page](http://oeis.org/A001400) I found formula to get needed values fast:

```
P(i) = round((i**3 + 3*i*i - 9*i*(i % 2))/144)
```